# How to set all the files in a directory read-only with Python?

Tags: python, windows, sharepoint, windows-10, onedrive

I am trying to set all the files of a folder in read-only mode in windows 10. I can do it one by one with os.chmod, but when I apply it to the folder, it doesn't work. Is there any way to do it without iterating? It is a long tree and that would be difficult. The files are located in a shared folder from OneDrive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why would it be difficult with iterating?

Comment: I don't know how to do it properly if the directory has many ramifications. There are folders, within folders, within folders.

Comment: `os.walk` will iterate that for you.

Comment: Oh my God that was much more easier than I thought. Thank you very much!

Comment: Feel free to post an answer to your own question if you have found a solution @amunozo